# char array copies whole word instead of single letter on last iteration

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void myStrcpy(char [], char []);  
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char c1[] = "htako";
    char c2[] = "Mark";

    myStrcpy(c1, c2);
    cout << c2 << endl;

    return 0;
}

void myStrcpy (char c1[], char c2[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while(c1[i] != '\0') {
        c2[i] = c1[i];
        cout << c1[i] << "  ::: " << i << endl;
        i++;
    }
}
```

When I step through the debugger everything works fine until i = 4, on the 4th interation it goes from (3rd iteration) htak to htakohtako. I do not understand why it copies the whole word over on the last iteration. When I print out c1[i] on the fourth iteration it prints out an o as expected but where does this extra htako come from at the end?

Comment: Why are you passing `char[]` and not `char*`? More importantly why are you writing your own `strcpy` in C++ where `std::string` exists?

Comment: Since this is C++, you could use `std::string`.

Comment: Ask yourself what is the size of c1 and c2, are they the same?

Comment: Arrays in C++ always have a *fixed size*. Once you have defined an array its size can not be changed.

Comment: Your copy function also forget to terminate the string in `c2`.

Comment: Ehh, [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) ..

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so what you're saying is this won't work because c1 is size 6 with null terminator and c2 is size 5 with the null terminator and you cant put 6 into 5.

Comment: @Omar That's correct.

Comment: let me play the devils advocate: Either the point of the exercise is that you find the solution yourself or you better use `std::string` or `std::copy`, but asking here how to fix it wont make you understand how to roll your own string stuff

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with your code:

- you are using c-based strings while forgetting to write terminating null char to `c2`
- you don't have enough space in `c2` for that null char.

To fix the first problem, add `c2[i] = 0;` after your while loop.

To fix the second one, use `char c2[6] = "Mark";`
Note that you need **6** here to hold 5 chars from "htako" + terminating null char.

In more detail: `char c1[] = "htako";` actually defines char array of length 6:

`{ 'h', 't', 'a', 'k', 'o', \0 }`.

`char c2[] = "Mark";` defines shorter char array of length 5:

`{ 'M', 'a', 'r', 'k', \0 }`

So when your while loop ends after coping c1 to c2, you have in the place of c2:

`{ 'h', 't', 'a', 'k', 'o' }`

Note that you don't have terminating null char. Also, cince c2 is implicitly declared to have length of 5, you don't have space to add it. So when you outputting the modified c2 to cout, since you are using char[], cout actually receives `char *` without length and, by C-strings convention, determines the length of the string by searching for terminating null char. Since you don't have that null char, cout will go past the end of `c2` searching for it and accessing data outside valid ares is an undefined behaviour for C++ program. On your particular machine, stack grows up so c1 happens to be right after c2 and  you see "htakohtako" printed. But really your program could also fail with SEGV or do any number of unplesant things. This type of error is called buffer overflow and is the root of many of security vulnerabilities. Avoid that at any cost.

---

But really, `std::string` is more suitable and safe option here, unless you are just playing around with how C strings work internally.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question has to do with how the memory is laid out. If you inspect the memory you would see:

```
c2              c1 
M, a, r, k, \0, h, t, a, k, o, \0
```

There are 2 problems in your code.

1. You have a buffer overflow `c2` is only 5 bytes (Mark + null terminator), but you are overwriting the null terminator since `c1` is 6 bytes long (htako + null terminator)
2. You are not null terminating your string

You are seeing the string appearing to grow because you overwrite the null terminator. In other situations your program may crash.

Comment: Note that, in general, "... you would see ..." should be "... you **might** see ...". There is no requirement for these arrays to be contiguous or in that particular order in memory. Granted, in this case, that order is probably the explanation for the results here.